# Google chrome rendering pdf fonts incorrectly

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, fonts

Some PDF files I open in Google chrome are completely unreadable, here's an example picture:

[image: here's an example picture.]

[This is the original PDF](http://www.megacad.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Produkte/MegaCAD_2017/MegaCAD_2017_Neuerungen.pdf).
They are shown fine on normal pdf viewers like Acrobat or Sumatra.

I have chrome version version 59 and haven't really found anything on the net.

What should I try?
Thanks for the help!

I also tried enabling or disabling hardware acceleration in chrome, but it didn't help. The problem is that there are no pdf viewer settings in chrome at all, so I have no idea what to try.

Comment: Did you change any font settings in chrome?

Comment: No, not that I can remember. They just contain the font size and the standard fonts, Times New Roman/Times New Roman/Arial/Consolas. I also installed the recommended "Advanced font settings" app, but I don't see anything that could help there either.

Comment: Same thing here. Developer Version of Chrome (dev channel), many extra fonts installed in the system. I didn't find a font which looks like that one on the screenshot, so may be it's some font built-in into chrome? As a workaround one can install a custom PDF extension, it worked for me by surprise with "Reverso Translate"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, just uninstalled a font called "Alien League Tech", rebooted, and all came back to normal. Explanation is here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/wrong-graffiti-font-in-apps-and-web-pages-after/eb9f39c0-989a-41a0-91d6-8b8ac44cc298

---

Other way of solving: Enabling the "Disable DirectWrite" experiment on the Chrome Flags page ( chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write ).

Answer (score 11):

Using Powershell with administrative privilegies, go to Fonts folder

```
cd c:/Windows/Fonts
```

than remove alien5.ttf

```
rm alien5.ttf
```

Windows 10 Fonts viewer via Windows Explorer doesn't show everything. There's a lot of fonts hidden underneath.

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Comment: After 7 years of trying every method, this was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't get any simpler than that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Same problem with strange "alien league" font being displayed in random pdf files.

I had to rename the file "alien5.ttf" (to "alien5.ttf.problem" ) using admin privileges in the \windows\font directory and then reboot. I could not figure out how to remove the font using normal windows tools. Windows explorer would not show the "alien" font when I was viewing the \windows\font directory.

I never want to see that font again. ever.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when you install a custom font and the file name falls in the line before Arial.ttf. :)
Copy the Arial.ttf file into a temporary directory, rename 001-arial.ttf and then install it to the Windows font.
The point is that the file extensions should be the first-ever TTF WINDOWS \ Fonts folder.