# Find out which Font masks as Arial?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, fonts

I have the same issue as [him, displaying fonts in PDF incorrectly](https://superuser.com/questions/1235124/google-chrome-rendering-pdf-fonts-incorrectly#)
The source of that problem as described in the linked description is a "bad" font, masking itself as "Arial"

In my case it simply is none of the fonts mentioned that causes the issue. It looks exactly as "Alien League" but that font does not appear to be installed and isn't listed in the Fonts-Directory. Because I have a lot of fonts installed: Is there a way/tool to find out, *which* font masks itself as Arial and so is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To find fonts that are masquerading as Arial, use `regedit` and navigate to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.

Look for a key named `Arial (TrueType)` but with a value other than `arial.ttf`.
Edit the value and change it back to `arial.ttf`.
That will restore the Arial Regular font, and will in effect uninstall the font that
is probably causing the problem. Check also all other fonts whose names begin with
`Arial`.

Another non-recommended workaround is to find a copy of `Arial.ttf` and re-install that.
This is not recommended because the existing Arial.ttf file will still stay present,
so this will cause multiple copies of it on your system.

Some broken fonts known to cause this problem are : Alien League, Brady Bunch, Linkin,
Jungle Life and Tall Sally. If installed, uninstalling will solve the problem.

For more information see the post
[Wrong, "graffiti" font in apps and Web pages after upgrade to Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/wrong-graffiti-font-in-apps-and-web-pages-after/eb9f39c0-989a-41a0-91d6-8b8ac44cc298).